# Change Temp Folder (Maps Location) Of Marble Widget In Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, marble

The Kde Marble Widget save downloaded files in a default folder (in app data I think)
I want change it to my custom location (for example app installation folder)
But I can't find any way

Comment: Installation folders under Program Files should not be writable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RichardCritten
I'm Developing insider app and know the installation folder will be writable

Comment: No what I mean is that having a user writable installation folder is a major security risk.

Comment: @RichardCritten 
I Know taht but I want run my app in a safe pc. In fact, it is a program for specific and safe people and it is not going to be published publicly.